# post array keep only 1 value

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post

PHP FORM CODE :

```
    echo '<form name="planeSeat" action="koltuk-sec-process.php" method="post" >';
...
    echo '<input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" id="'.$rightplace.'" name="artwork" value="'.$rightplace.'"  />';
...
    echo '<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Üye girişi yapmadan devam et"/>';
```

PHP PROCESS CODE :

```
    $rest1 = array();
    $rest2 = array();

$rest1[] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["artwork"]);
$rest2[] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["artwork2"]);

   if($rest1 != null){

    print_r ($rest1);

    }

    if($rest2 != null){

    print_r ($rest2);

    }
```

When I send artwork, if I selected 2 checkboxes, `$rest1` only keeps the last value. How can I send my all values?

Comment: Show your complete form code, so we may help you then.

Comment: perhaps you should have `artwork[]` in your form checkbox name rather than `artwork`

Comment: Use `isset()` insted of `!= null` and remove `[]` from `$rest1[]`,`$rest2[]`

Comment: I tried artwork[] did not work

Comment: @MarkBaker: Guess ok, but does not result in `artwork2` then

Comment: Where is artwork2 supposed to come from, because it doesn't appear in your form inputs

Comment: `echo '<input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" id="'.$l.'" name="artwork2" value="'.$l.'"  />';` i have also `artwork2` in my form

Comment: Show your form code! But I doubt that it is YOUR code...

Comment: my form 4333 characters i can not send

Comment: You do $a = $b, and $c = $d. So how would you expect $a to have 2 values?

Comment: @gokcokkececi share result of `var_dump($_POST);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably wanted to code

```
$rest1[] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["artwork"]);
$rest1[] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["artwork2"]);
```

instead of

```
$rest1[] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["artwork"]);
$rest2[] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["artwork2"]);
```

Comment: Hope this is what the OP wants, not really clear his question ;)

Answer (score 0):

For one result, [break](https://www.php.net/break) should do the trick:

```
$foobar = array('uno', 'dos', 'tres');
foreach ($foobar as $fb) {
    echo '<p>'.$fb.'</p>';
    break;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

the reason is simple : in case of multiple checkbox checked with the same name, you have to specified an array for the checkbox name, this way you will be able to traverse the posted values

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" id="'.$rightplace.'" name="artwork[]" value="'.$rightplace.'"  />';

echo '<input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" id="'.$rightplace.'" name="artwork[]" value="'.$rightplace.'"  />'; // second checkbox



print_r ( $_POST['artwork'] ) // will display the artwork array
```

all of your checkbox with similar content should have the same name !!!!!

Comment: Sorry the html output didn t write out on the first post